# exit immediately after failure and echo error message to before exiting shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, exit

i have a script that should exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status and i want to echo sth to log before i exit:

```
set -e
command A || (echo "A failed";exit 1)
command B || (echo "B failed";exit 1)
if Condition C;
then
   command D || (echo "D failed";exit 1)
```

it does what i want. If it failed in command A/B/D, echo correct message to me and exit. I know () means subshell and in subshell it echos something then return false in subshell(exit 1), so it's "false || false" and thus exit in main shell. My question is, is that the same as:

```
#set -e
    command A || { echo "A failed";exit 1; }
    command B || { echo "B failed";exit 1; }
    if Condition C;
    then
       command D || {echo "D failed";exit 1; }
```

if not, what's the difference? In my test, they behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the second version, `exit 1` exits the original shell, not the subshell. That's why you don't need `set -e` to make the script exit when that happens.

You could get the equivalent of the first shell like this:

```
set -e
command A || { echo "A failed";false; }
command B || { echo "B failed";false; }
if Condition C;
then
   command D || {echo "D failed";false; }
```

`false` exits with a non-zero status, which will trigger `set -e` to exit the shell.

Comment: thanks.  what's the best practice in this case?  From my view, i think all these three approach is the same right?

Comment: to achieve my goal

Comment: Explicit is usually better. Use `exit` when you want to exit the script at a specific place. `set -e` should be used if you want to exit after unexpected errors. If you want to log something whenever you exit, use `trap EXIT` or `trap ERR`

Comment: what if i want to exit after unexpected errors?(because it's an essential script and we would like to be alarmed whatever is wrong). I think i should still use "set -e", but instead of using "|| (echo "xxx";exit 1)", i can use TRAP errorfun EXIT to log before i exit?

Comment: It would be awesome if `set -e` would simply exit after unexpected errors, but [the reality is significantly uglier](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes, I was simplifying, classigying all the errors that you check explicitly with `if` and `||` as "expected"